# How to make multiple choice quiz in html and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to make a quiz that takes the users choices, extracts the value of the chosen answer and performs a calculation to tally up the answer type that the user chose most. The way I am currently doing it is through

```
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1"> 
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="2">
```

fields and doing a Request.Form["Q1"]... as the variables in my

```
Results(string Q1, string Q2, ....)
```

function. I want to make these buttons entirely clickable within a div, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: Can you just put those in a div tag? Looks like you have the radio buttons down

Comment: Can you please post some more code? Your question can not describe the problem properly.